# Unable to change the tab icons while using FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, fragmentstatepageradapter

Im usign the following code to change the icon of selected tab. Im using view pager with FragmentStatePagerAdapter.

```
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
            viewPager.setSelected(true);
            tab.setIcon(R.drawable.status);
        } else if (tab.getPosition() == 1){
            tab.setIcon(R.drawable.status);
            viewPager.setSelected(true);
        }else if (tab.getPosition() == 2){
            tab.setIcon(R.drawable.status);
            viewPager.setSelected(true);
        }else if (tab.getPosition() == 3){
            tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_share);
            viewPager.setSelected(true);
        }
        //also you can use tab.setsetCustomView() too
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
            tab.setIcon(R.drawable.status_inactive);
            viewPager.setSelected(false);

        } else if (tab.getPosition() == 1){
            tab.setIcon(R.drawable.rating_inactive);
            viewPager.setSelected(false);

        }else if (tab.getPosition() == 2){
            tab.setIcon(R.drawable.photos_inactive);
            viewPager.setSelected(false);

        }else if (tab.getPosition() == 3){
            tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_share);
            viewPager.setSelected(false);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
});
```

the problem is,

1. The icon is not being changed though I have changed it.
2. When I swipe, it goes to the next tab. But, when I select a tab, the tab is selected but the contents of the tab is not changed and its still the content of the existing tab.

How can I sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make tab selector and deselector you can use this way

**1.Create Custom view and Inflate it:**

```
private View getTabView(int imgDrawable) {
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.tab_view, null);
        ImageView imgTab = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgTab);
        imgTab.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(imgDrawable));

        return view;
    }
```

**2.Create drawable Selector**

tab_home_selector.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_home_selected" android:state_selected="true" />
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_home_deselected" />
    </selector>
```

**3.Insert in tab:**

```
tabDashboardLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabDashboardLayout);        
        //Adding the tabs using addTab() method
        View tabView = getTabView(R.drawable.tab_home_selector);;
        tabDashboardLayout.addTab(tabDashboardLayout.newTab().setCustomView(tabView));
```

For individual tab you to have create individual drawable selector and add to tab