# How to create Tabs with icons and text TabLayout android

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I am working on an android app and wants to create a layout like below.

[image]

I want to make the Tabs same as shown in this layout which will be scrolling horizontally. I want to set the icons of reactions and text on these tabs. The Icons are the server images which I need to show, but I have no idea how can I show server url images in the tabs as icons.

Is there any other way of making this layout except `TabLayout` or Sliding `TabLayout` with which I can get the same `UI` as in image?

Please help if anyone know how to do this.

Comment: You can refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37650128/unable-to-change-the-tab-icons-while-using-fragmentstatepageradapter/37650323#37650323

Answer (score 1):

**ViewPager Adapter**

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private static int NUM_ITEMS = 2;
private Context mContext;
private String[] tabText;



public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager, Context context) {
    super(fragmentManager);
    this.mContext = context;
    this.tabText = new String[]{
            "First tab",
            "second tab"
    };



}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new FirstFragment();
        case 1:
            return new SecondFragment();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NUM_ITEMS;
}

  @Override
  public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
   return tabText[position];
 }
```

}

**MainActivity.Java**

```
    private int[] imageResId = {// icon resource };
    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tl_viewer);
    mViewpager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.vp_viewer);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewpager);


   //Method to set up tab layout icon
   private void setUpTabIcon() {
    for (int i = 0; i < mTabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {

        mTabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(imageResId[i]);


    }

}
```

Tab count and Tab text picked from ViewPager Adapter. and icon picked from **setTabIcon** method

Comment: Thanks for the code, the code is really helpful. But my problem is that my images are coming from server in form of urls, then how can I set them to the tabs as icons. I don't have drawable images saved in my resources directory. Please give me some suggestion, if you have nay idea about this.

Comment: mTabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(Drawable d) this function will accept drawable. you can use any library Picasso , Glide etc to download your image and then convert that image into drawable and set on Tab icon.

Answer (score 0):

Please use Below link of Android hive. Android Hive Explain very well for working with TabLayout -

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have an custom layout for your tabs.
See this link [How to set icon next to text in tablayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34370081/how-to-set-icon-next-to-text-in-tablayout?rq=1)

And to answer your another query of displaying the server images, you can use a library for that purpose like http://square.github.io/picasso/